# How to reset these CSS styles?

Tags: css

I'm searching for the way to reset these (for mobile version of site):

```
#somediv {

    /* Internet Explorer 10 */
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    -ms-box-orient: vertical;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;

    /* Firefox */
    display: -moz-box;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;

    /* Safari, Opera, and Chrome */
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;

    /* REGULAR */
    display: box;
    box-orient: vertical;
    box-pack: center;
    box-align: center;

}
```

I have tried setting just "display: block" one time. But some browsers (emulator) seem to still have the previously set rules.. Should I just use "none" on them all?

Comment: The general browser-agent style for a div is block. Try display: block;

Comment: It seems I have to reset -orient, -pack and -align too..

Comment: Okay, I see you tried `display: block` already. You might want to reset the other properties as well. `display: none;` won't help you, as it will hide the div.

Comment: off course display: none won't help.. ;)

Comment: According to MDN box-orient, box-pack and box-align only apply if the display value is set to box or inline-box. It shouldn't be necessary to reset those values. Here are the default values according to MDN if you want to try it anyway: `box-orient: inline-axis;` , `box-pack: start;` and `box-align: stretch;`

Comment: @mowgli How do you overwrite your above rules? Have you checked (with the Webdeveloper Tools of your browser) that your "override" style is applied?

Comment: I just found out that it's iphone especially that adds padding/margin to that svg element.. so I'm gonna investigate that

Comment: Oh, no. Here is the reason: I set the width (with css) to be smaller than the svg originally is set to, but some browsers then add top/bottom whitespace instead of scaling vertically too. It's a bug I guess

Answer (score 0):

You can use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) for applying specific styles to different mobile devices.

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
#somediv{
  display:block!important;
}
}
```

Try giving the `display:block` with `!important` so as to prevent it from getting overridden

Comment: Also, a media query based on max-width doesn't necessarily only apply to mobile devices. I think @mowgli issue is based on flexbox support rather than screensize. You could detect flexbox support with a feature test in javascript or use modernizr and redefine the css rule based on that test.